# View shifts under status bar when not expected - then corrects itself

Tags: iphone

I have a view controller that flips in to provide basic app info. When this view initially loads, it slides under the status bar, shifting the entire view up 20 pixels. The xib file is built with the status bar in place - but the view is shifter up, and has 20 blank pixels at the bottom.

But if I transition back to the main part of the app, and the go to this view again later, the view shifts down 20 pixels, and then looks as it should - even though I've taken no action that would cause the view to shift.  The code below may not shed any light on this issue - but any idea what's going on here?

```
if (self.infoViewController == nil) {
        infoViewController = 
        [[InfoViewController alloc ] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
    }

    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:infoViewController.view duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

In this context, I think you may have written code for hiding the status bar in the infoViewController. Or else while creating the infoViewController nib file, unexpectedly you may set the statausbar to None.

[image: It may be set like this]

Change the status bar value.

[image: You Have to set like this in the IB]

So once check those, your problem will be solved.

Comment: That's not it.  The nib file is set to use a status bar. THe weird thing is that the position of the view changes to the correct locale after the app has been in use - but the first time the view controller is loaded, the entire view is shifted up 20 pixels.

Comment: okay, once set the infoViewController.view.frame to required position. it may solve your problem